# $A = (\cos t, \sin t)$. $A$ represents an object moving counterclockwise. Is $[-\sin t, \cos t]$ a vector that describes the object’s velocity?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, vectors, circles

$A = (\cos (t), \sin (t))$

'$A$' represents an object moving counterclockwise at a speed of 1 unit per second on the unit circle (radians).

At point '$A$' Hela says that $[-\sin (t), \cos(t)]$ is a vector that describes the object’s velocity. Is this true?

So I know that the derivative of $\cos (t)$ is $-\sin (t)$ and the derivative of $\sin (t)$ is $\cos (t)$. How does this show that the vector works?

Comment: Yes, since the velocity is the time derivative of the position vector.

Comment: Is there a reason why this works?

Comment: The velocity is by definition the time-derivative of the position.  Since our frame is time-invariant, it reduces to differentiating the components.  By the way, you should really just pick one notation and stick with it, instead of jumping between parenthesis and square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, this is indeed the velocity, since it is the derivative of the position. Nonetheless, I want to point out a fact that may convince you further:

Geometrically, one may notice that the velocity of an object describing a circle must be perpendicular to its position. And this is exactly the case for the vector you mentioned, as we see evaluating the dot product between these two vectors:

$[\cos(t), \sin(t)] \cdot [-\sin(t), \cos(t)] = -\cos(t)*\sin(t) + \sin(t)*\cos(t) = 0$

Once the dot product is zero, they are perpendicular, as wanted.

P.S. I don't know if the distinction between parenthesis and square brackets in your question was to differentiate points and vectors, but this differentiation is somewhat relavant and I would be happy if it was on purpose. It is not as evident in R^2, because the two notions merge, but it is crucial in more general frameworks, for instance in manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's true,what the velocity is trying to say is that at time t ,it's velocity is described by

$$\langle-\sin(t),\cos(t)\rangle$$

this means that at moment to move to the next point, the vector travels in counter-clockwise direction with this velocity.
I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec{A}$ represents the position of the object, then $\vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{A}}{dt}$ is the velocity. So yes, it is true:
$\vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{A}}{dt} = \left(-\sin t, \cos t\right)$, and
$\lvert \vec{v} \rvert = \sqrt{ \left(-\sin^2 t\right)+\left(\cos^2 t\right)}$ = 1

The magnitude of the velocity vector will always be $1$. Also, it is clear that the object will always be on the unit circle too, since
$\lvert \vec{A} \rvert = \sqrt{ \left(\cos^2 t\right)+\left(\sin^2 t\right)}$ = 1.

Answer (score 0):

$A = (\cos t, \sin t); B=(-\sin t, \cos t);$

Motions $(A,B)$ have start points $(1,0), (0,1)$ with unit speed in anticlockwise and clockwise directions respectively.